# preimage of joint random variables and integration

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, I need to determine the two sets A and B that will make the following equation true

$Pr ((X^{-1}, Y^{-1}) (A \times B)) = \int _{-\infty} ^{t} f_{Y}(y) F_{X} (y) dy $

where $f_{Y}$ is the PDF of $Y$, and $F_{X}$ is the CDF of $X$

Can we write the event that corresponds to this integration in this form using the preimage of the random variables and the product of two sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

$$F_{X} (y)=\int_{-\infty}^y f_X(x)dx$$
we have

$$\int _{-\infty} ^{t} f_{Y}(y) F_{X} (y) dy=\int _{-\infty} ^{t} f_{Y}(y) \left[\int_{-\infty}^y f_X(x)dx\right]dy=$$$$=\int_{-\infty}^t\int_{-\infty}^yf_Y(y)f_X(x)\ dxdy=\iint_{\{(x,y):\ x\leq y,\ y\leq t\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx dy.$$
This is a double integral of the joint probability density function over the region showed below:

[image]

That is

$$\int _{-\infty} ^{t} f_{Y}(y) F_{X} (y) dy=P(Y\leq t\ \cap\ X\leq Y).$$

So the given integral cannot be written in the form of

$$P((X^{-1}, Y^{-1}) (A \times B)). $$

Comment: when you say that it cannot be written in this form, do you mean that it cannot be written using the product of two sets, or it cannot be written even using the preimage of the random variables. I mean can I still write it using the preimage of the two random variables of a single set?

Comment: I meant that the region is not rectangular. THat is, it cannot be written as a product of two intervals. $$\{\omega: Y\leq t\ \cap\ X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)\}$$ is the pre image.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  how can I go from the probability of this event to the integration form? If I have this relation   
$P(X^{-1} (A)) = \int \textbf {1} _{A} dF_{X}$
how can I use it to find the probability of the event that you mentioned?

Comment: You cannot calculate the probability: $P((X^{-1}, Y^{-1}) (A \times B))$ in the form of $P(X^{-1}(A))=\int_A\ dF_X$. That probability, as an integral is given as $$\iint_{\{(x,y):\ x\leq y,\ y\leq t\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx dy.$$

Comment: I understand that I cannot use it in its current form and that it should be with respect to both random variables. my question is that how can I use this relation and change it to reach the required integration?
for example, if I change it to 
$P((X^{-1}, Y^{-1})(A)) = \int \textbf{1}_{A} dF_{XY}$ 
what will be the set A and how can I use it to reach this integration ?  

$\int _{-\infty} ^{t} f_{Y}(y) F_{X} (y) dy$

Comment: This exactly what I've described in my answer. $A=\{(x,y):\ x\leq y,\ y\leq t\}$ and you integrate the joint density over $A $.

Comment: OK, I get your point, can I split this indicator function $\textbf{1}_{A}$ into the multiplication of two indicator functions one for x and one for y? or it will be similar to trying to write the set in the Cartesian product form which as you mentioned cannot be done

Comment: That is similar... You cannot because $A$ is not a rectangle.

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: hi, could you please help me in this question ?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724078/probability-of-events-of-three-independent-random-variables