# How can I use the integration to evaluate the probability of an event?

Tags: probability-theory

Assume we have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. If I am trying to find $\operatorname{Pr}(X < Y < k)$ , it will equal to 
$$
  \iint_{\mathbb R^{2}}
  1_{A} f_{Y} (y) \cdot  f_{X} (x)
  \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $A$ is the set in the borel space that corresponds to the probability event $(X < Y < k)$, i.e., $A = \{(x,y) \mid x < y < k \}$.

Now, if I want to find a probability of an event that lies outside the event $X < Y$. Since it lies outside $X<Y$, this means that the integral above should be equal to $0$. My question is, how can I use the integral to say that this value equals to zero (the probability of any event that doesn't belong to the event set $X < Y$ using this integral will equal to $0$).

For example, let us take the event ($Y < X < k$), the probability of this event can be represented as:

$$
  \iint_{\mathbb R^{2}}
  1_{A_{1}} f_{Y} (y) \cdot  f_{X} (x)
  \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x
$$

where $A_{1}= \{(x,y) \mid y < x < k \}$.

If I want to use the first integral to find $\operatorname{Pr}(Y < X < k)$, the integral should equal $0$. So the question is how can I evaluate the value of the integral to be $0$ without going back to the corresponding probability event?

Comment: What is "the set in the borel space that corresponds to the probability event $(X < Y < k)$"? Do you mean $$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x<y<k\}\ ?$$ Then the integral should be written $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\mathbf 1_A(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,dxdy$$ and is, by definition, $$\int_{-\infty}^kf_X(x)\int_x^kf_Y(y)dy\,dx$$ or, equivalently,  $$\int_{-\infty}^kf_Y(y)\int_{-\infty}^yf_X(x)dx\,dy$$

Comment: yes this is the set, and both versions of the integral will work. but my question is how can I use this integral to say that if any value of $Y > X$ then this integral will equal to $0$? I know that if  I go back to the event set in the probability space, that for any $Y>X$ , {s | X s < Y s} will be empty end consequently the  probability will be $0$. but my question here, how can I tell that for any Y > X this integral will be $0$ using just the integral and the indicator function?

Comment: FYI, the phrases "if any value of Y>X" and "for any Y>X" (twice), are meaningless. Would you be confusing random variables (i.e. *functions*) with real numbers?

Comment: @Did the random variables eventually return numbers when applied to samples in the probability space, right?

Comment: Yes, and what is your point?

Comment: @Did, I don't get you point that I am confusing random variables with real numbers, could you please explain this more?

Comment: @Did, I have edited the question, could you please help me  with it

Comment: Sorry but you accepted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2663985/) six months ago, which fully answers your numerous subsequent questions on exactly the same topic, the present one included. Which game is this?

Comment: "I edited the question to reflect the comments below" If only.

Comment: At that time I was trying to find the set that corresponds to the event (X < Y) , now I am trying to use this set to say that any point that lies outside it , the integral will equal to $0$, without going back to the probability event in the sample space. I am not really trying to play any game, I am trying to learn here

Comment: ??? Sorry but until you decide to use conventional lexicon and notions, there is little point to this exchange.

Comment: I am here to learn, as this is the intention of this whole website. so if you see that there is a problem with my questions or the notions that I am using, you can direct me to the right path instead of voting down all my questions!!!

Comment: and please don't close this question, maybe someone else will be patient enough to help me with this

Comment: 1. How do you know what I vote? 2. Sorry but when the gap between the notions mobilized and their grasp by the OP is too large (to the point that even the *words* used are absurd), how do you suggest to proceed? (I mean, except by crying "Not my fault, not my fault, I am here to learn"?) Please be specific.

Comment: "maybe someone else will be patient enough to help me with this" Just like the OP who answered you 6 months ago? And the comedy will go on...

Comment: @Did Thank you for trying to make fun of people who are just trying to learn.  maybe you have advanced knowledge, but this doesn't give you the right to use such words "comedy and games" with someone who is just trying to gain more knowledge, thank you again

Comment: Why do you avoid answering the **quite specific queries** I formulated? Because it is easier to pose as a victim than to use the site properly? Enough for me. All the best.